# Do kids or infants count as a second person when using a US HOV or carpool lane?

Tags: usa, transportation

Let's say I've traveling across the United States by car, or visiting from another country.

HOV (high occupancy vehicle) or carpool lanes are designed to remove extra cars from the road. If I'm traveling with non-drivers like children or infants, do they count? Does it matter which state I'm in?

Comment: It's day time in America right now.  Are you in America? What state if so?

Comment: [California DOT](http://www.dot.ca.gov/hq/paffairs/faq/faq79.htm) says kids count as long as they're not still in the womb.

Comment: Don't have time to link a source, but Northern Virginia/DC/Maryland, infants in car seats count towards the total persons in car for carpool lanes as well.

Comment: Admittedly, not worded as a "traveler" question, but it's something I might want to know if traveling across the US, or visiting from another country. If I edit to try to make it more on-topic, maybe we can reopen it? Or should it be migrated to [law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I swear I'm not doing this just for the votes...!

Answer (score 13):

If this question refers to the United States, the federal department of transportation says in all states:

[Frequently Asked HOV Questions](http://ops.fhwa.dot.gov/freewaymgmt/faq.htm#faq13)

> 13. Do children and infants count as passengers?
>       Yes. All states with HOV facilities count children and infants as passengers.

HOV = high occupancy vehicle also known as a carpool lane

Comment: However, depending on this may cause a delay. One of my friends driving with her then infant daughter was ordered to pull over by a traffic cop who had not seen the child. There was, of course, no ticket, but they had to wait at the side of the road longer than it would have taken her to go through the non-HOV lane.